# How to utilize ScrollSpy Bootstrap to automatically scroll overflow-x horizontal navigation

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, scrollspy

Looking for some assistance with my current horizontal scrolling nav with utilization of Bootstraps ScrollSpy. I have many items in my navigation for a clean timeline effect. However, I would love for the .nav-link item to automatically scroll the navigation when the user scrolls vertically. This way the time stamp stays current. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```css
html * {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 10rem;
}

.nav-pills {
  overflow: visible;
  -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 5px;
}

.nav-pills a {
  color: red;
}

.nav-pills a:hover {
  color: #0094a4;
}

.nav-pills .nav-link.active {
  background-color: red;
}

.navbar .combine-info:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: .7;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: .2s;
}

.navbar .combine-info:active {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.96);
  transform: scale(0.96);
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: .2s;
}

.navbar .combine-info-bubble {
  width: 21rem;
  border-radius: 1.5rem;
  border: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 999999;
  color: red;
}

.timeline {
  position: fixed;
  top: 1.8rem;
  left: 59%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
  transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
  z-index: 999;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
  width: 68rem;
  border-radius: .5rem;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  overflow-x: auto;
  cursor: -webkit-grab !important;
  cursor: grab !important;
}

.nav-pills .nav-link {
  cursor: -webkit-grab !important;
  cursor: grab !important;
}

.right {
  margin-left: 35%;
}


/* Card Styling */

.card {
  width: 50rem;
  margin-top: 7rem;
  min-height: 32rem;
  margin-bottom: 4rem;
  border-radius: .8rem;
  border: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center top;
  color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.card:hover {
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.05) rotate(1deg);
  transform: scale(1.05) rotate(1deg);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.card .card-body {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.card .card-title {
  font-size: 2.1rem;
  font-family: 'Auxilia-Bold', sans-serif;
}

.card .card-subtitle {
  font-size: 1.3em;
}

.card .card-text {
  font-size: .9rem;
}

.card .card-time {
  font-size: 3.8rem;
  text-align: left;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px white;
  color: transparent;
  font-family: 'Auxilia-Bold', sans-serif;
}

.card .card-more {
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  text-align: right;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 1rem;
  right: 2rem;
}

.card .card-more:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: .7;
}

.card .card-more:active {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.96);
  transform: scale(0.96);
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: .2s;
}

.card .card-more .bi-arrow-right-circle {
  padding-left: .2rem;
}

.left {
  margin-right: 35%;
}

.story-1 {
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(10%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), to(black)), url("../images/cards/card-1-bg.jpg");
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 10%, black 100%), url("../images/cards/card-1-bg.jpg");
  -webkit-box-shadow: -12px -12px 0px #f2b6a6ca, -22px -22px 0px #f2b6a67d;
  box-shadow: -12px -12px 0px #f2b6a6ca, -22px -22px 0px #f2b6a67d;
}

.story-2 {
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(10%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), to(black)), url("../images/cards/card-2-bg.jpg");
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 10%, black 100%), url("../images/cards/card-2-bg.jpg");
  -webkit-box-shadow: 12px -12px 0px #f1e6d7, 22px -22px 0px #efe9e2a5;
  box-shadow: 12px -12px 0px #f1e6d7, 22px -22px 0px #efe9e2a5;
}

.story-3 {
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(10%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), to(black)), url("../images/cards/card-3-bg.jpg");
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 10%, black 100%), url("../images/cards/card-3-bg.jpg");
  -webkit-box-shadow: -12px -12px 0px #c8e2f6dd, -22px -22px 0px #e4f4ff86;
  box-shadow: -12px -12px 0px #c8e2f6dd, -22px -22px 0px #e4f4ff86;
}

.story-4 {
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(15%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), to(black)), url("../images/cards/card-4-bg.jpg");
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 15%, black 100%), url("../images/cards/card-4-bg.jpg");
  -webkit-box-shadow: 12px -12px 0px #2d659cc8, 22px -22px 0px #2d659c60;
  box-shadow: 12px -12px 0px #2d659cc8, 22px -22px 0px #2d659c60;
}

.story-5 {
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(15%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), to(black)), url("../images/cards/card-5-bg.jpg");
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 15%, black 100%), url("../images/cards/card-5-bg.jpg");
  -webkit-box-shadow: -12px -12px 0px #c8e2f6dd, -22px -22px 0px #e4f4ff86;
  box-shadow: -12px -12px 0px #c8e2f6dd, -22px -22px 0px #e4f4ff86;
}

.story-6 {
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(15%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), to(black)), url("../images/cards/card-6-bg.jpg");
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 15%, black 100%), url("../images/cards/card-6-bg.jpg");
  -webkit-box-shadow: 12px -12px 0px #2d659cc8, 22px -22px 0px #2d659c60;
  box-shadow: 12px -12px 0px #2d659cc8, 22px -22px 0px #2d659c60;
}

.story-7 {
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(15%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), to(black)), url("../images/cards/card-7-bg.jpg");
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 15%, black 100%), url("../images/cards/card-7-bg.jpg");
  -webkit-box-shadow: -12px -12px 0px #c8e2f6dd, -22px -22px 0px #e4f4ff86;
  box-shadow: -12px -12px 0px #c8e2f6dd, -22px -22px 0px #e4f4ff86;
}

.story-8 {
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(15%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), to(black)), url("../images/cards/card-8-bg.jpg");
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 15%, black 100%), url("../images/cards/card-8-bg.jpg");
  -webkit-box-shadow: 12px -12px 0px #2d659cc8, 22px -22px 0px #2d659c60;
  box-shadow: 12px -12px 0px #2d659cc8, 22px -22px 0px #2d659c60;
}

.story-9 {
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(15%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), to(black)), url("../images/cards/card-9-bg.jpg");
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 15%, black 100%), url("../images/cards/card-9-bg.jpg");
  -webkit-box-shadow: -12px -12px 0px #c8e2f6dd, -22px -22px 0px #e4f4ff86;
  box-shadow: -12px -12px 0px #c8e2f6dd, -22px -22px 0px #e4f4ff86;
}

.story-10 {
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(15%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), to(black)), url("../images/cards/card-10-bg.jpg");
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 15%, black 100%), url("../images/cards/card-10-bg.jpg");
  -webkit-box-shadow: 12px -12px 0px #2d659cc8, 22px -22px 0px #2d659c60;
  box-shadow: 12px -12px 0px #2d659cc8, 22px -22px 0px #2d659c60;
}

.story-11 {
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(15%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), to(black)), url("../images/cards/card-11-bg.jpg");
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 15%, black 100%), url("../images/cards/card-11-bg.jpg");
  -webkit-box-shadow: -12px -12px 0px #c8e2f6dd, -22px -22px 0px #e4f4ff86;
  box-shadow: -12px -12px 0px #c8e2f6dd, -22px -22px 0px #e4f4ff86;
}

.story-12 {
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(15%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), to(black)), url("../images/cards/");
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 15%, black 100%), url("../images/cards/");
  -webkit-box-shadow: 12px -12px 0px #2d659cc8, 22px -22px 0px #2d659c60;
  box-shadow: 12px -12px 0px #2d659cc8, 22px -22px 0px #2d659c60;
}

.story-13 {
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(15%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), to(black)), url("../images/cards/card-13-bg.jpg");
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 15%, black 100%), url("../images/cards/card-13-bg.jpg");
  -webkit-box-shadow: -12px -12px 0px #c8e2f6dd, -22px -22px 0px #e4f4ff86;
  box-shadow: -12px -12px 0px #c8e2f6dd, -22px -22px 0px #e4f4ff86;
}

.story-14 {
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(15%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), to(black)), url("../images/cards/card-14-bg.jpg");
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 15%, black 100%), url("../images/cards/card-14-bg.jpg");
  -webkit-box-shadow: 12px -12px 0px #2d659cc8, 22px -22px 0px #2d659c60;
  box-shadow: 12px -12px 0px #2d659cc8, 22px -22px 0px #2d659c60;
}

.story-15 {
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(15%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), to(black)), url("../images/cards/card-15-bg.jpg");
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 15%, black 100%), url("../images/cards/card-15-bg.jpg");
  -webkit-box-shadow: -12px -12px 0px #c8e2f6dd, -22px -22px 0px #e4f4ff86;
  box-shadow: -12px -12px 0px #c8e2f6dd, -22px -22px 0px #e4f4ff86;
}

.story-16 {
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(15%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), to(black)), url("../images/cards/card-16-bg.jpg");
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 15%, black 100%), url("../images/cards/card-16-bg.jpg");
  -webkit-box-shadow: 12px -12px 0px #2d659cc8, 22px -22px 0px #2d659c60;
  box-shadow: 12px -12px 0px #2d659cc8, 22px -22px 0px #2d659c60;
}

.story-17 {
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(15%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), to(black)), url("../images/cards/card-17-bg.jpg");
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 15%, black 100%), url("../images/cards/card-17-bg.jpg");
  -webkit-box-shadow: -12px -12px 0px #c8e2f6dd, -22px -22px 0px #e4f4ff86;
  box-shadow: -12px -12px 0px #c8e2f6dd, -22px -22px 0px #e4f4ff86;
}

.story-18 {
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(15%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), to(black)), url("../images/cards/card-18-bg.jpg");
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 15%, black 100%), url("../images/cards/card-18-bg.jpg");
  -webkit-box-shadow: 12px -12px 0px #2d659cc8, 22px -22px 0px #2d659c60;
  box-shadow: 12px -12px 0px #2d659cc8, 22px -22px 0px #2d659c60;
}

.story-19 {
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(15%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), to(black)), url("../images/cards/card-19-bg.jpg");
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 15%, black 100%), url("../images/cards/card-19-bg.jpg");
  -webkit-box-shadow: -12px -12px 0px #c8e2f6dd, -22px -22px 0px #e4f4ff86;
  box-shadow: -12px -12px 0px #c8e2f6dd, -22px -22px 0px #e4f4ff86;
}

.story-20 {
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(15%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), to(black)), url("../images/cards/card-20-bg.jpg");
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 15%, black 100%), url("../images/cards/card-20-bg.jpg");
  -webkit-box-shadow: 12px -12px 0px #2d659cc8, 22px -22px 0px #2d659c60;
  box-shadow: 12px -12px 0px #2d659cc8, 22px -22px 0px #2d659c60;
}

.story-21 {
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(15%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), to(black)), url("../images/cards/card-21-bg.jpg");
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 15%, black 100%), url("../images/cards/card-21-bg.jpg");
  -webkit-box-shadow: -12px -12px 0px #c8e2f6dd, -22px -22px 0px #e4f4ff86;
  box-shadow: -12px -12px 0px #c8e2f6dd, -22px -22px 0px #e4f4ff86;
}


/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

```html
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="navbar" data-offset="50">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-light fixed-top pt-3 pb-4" aria-label="Tenth navbar example" id="navbar-example">
    <div class="timeline">
      <ul class="nav navbar-collapse nav-pills" role="tablist">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#item-1">5:00 AM</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="#item-2">7:00 AM</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="#item-3">7:05 AM</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="#item-4">8:00 AM</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="#item-5">8:15 AM</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="#item-6">9:00 AM</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="#item-7">9:15 AM</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="#item-8">10:00 AM</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="#item-9">11:02 AM</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="#item-10">11:45 AM</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="#item-11">12:15 PM</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="#item-12">2:15 PM</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="#item-13">3:45 PM</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="#item-14">4:03 PM</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="#item-15">4:42 PM</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="#item-16">5:05 PM</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="#item-17">5:13 PM</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="#item-18">8:07 PM</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="#item-19">9:03 PM</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="#item-20">10:30 PM</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="#item-21">2:30 AM</a>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="container">

    <div class="row schedule">
      <div id="item-1">
        <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-anchor-placement="center-bottom" data-aos-duration="1200">
          <div class="card left story-1" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modal1">
            <div class="card-body">

              <h5 class="card-subtitle ">A long day begins </h5>
              <p class="card-time">5:00 AM</p>
            </div>
            <p class="card-more">Read More <i class="bi bi-arrow-right-circle"></i></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="item-2">
        <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-anchor-placement="center-bottom" data-aos-duration="1200">
          <div class="card right story-2" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modal2">
            <div class="card-body">

              <h5 class="card-subtitle ">Cafe Patachou opens it's doors </h5>
              <p class="card-time">7:00 AM</p>
            </div>
            <p class="card-more">Read More <i class="bi bi-arrow-right-circle"></i></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="item-3">
        <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-anchor-placement="center-bottom" data-aos-duration="1200">
          <div class="card left story-3" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modal3">
            <div class="card-body">

              <h5 class="card-subtitle ">"I wake up early and like to get a workout in"</h5>
              <p class="card-time">7:05 AM</p>
            </div>
            <p class="card-more">Read More <i class="bi bi-arrow-right-circle"></i></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="item-4">
        <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-anchor-placement="center-bottom" data-aos-duration="1200">
          <div class="card right story-4" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modal4">
            <div class="card-body">

              <h5 class="card-subtitle ">Team Personnel Get Ready For The Bench Press</h5>
              <p class="card-time">8:00 AM</p>
            </div>
            <p class="card-more">Read More <i class="bi bi-arrow-right-circle"></i></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="item-5">
        <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-anchor-placement="center-bottom" data-aos-duration="1200">
          <div class="card left story-5" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modal5">
            <div class="card-body">

              <h5 class="card-subtitle ">"I wake up early and like to get a workout in"</h5>
              <p class="card-time">8:15 AM</p>
            </div>
            <p class="card-more">Read More <i class="bi bi-arrow-right-circle"></i></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="item-6">
        <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-anchor-placement="center-bottom" data-aos-duration="1200">
          <div class="card right story-6" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modal6">
            <div class="card-body">

              <h5 class="card-subtitle ">Team Personnel Get Ready For The Bench Press</h5>
              <p class="card-time">9:00 AM</p>
            </div>
            <p class="card-more">Read More <i class="bi bi-arrow-right-circle"></i></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="item-7">
        <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-anchor-placement="center-bottom" data-aos-duration="1200">
          <div class="card left story-7" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modal7">
            <div class="card-body">

              <h5 class="card-subtitle ">"I wake up early and like to get a workout in"</h5>
              <p class="card-time">9:15 AM</p>
            </div>
            <p class="card-more">Read More <i class="bi bi-arrow-right-circle"></i></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="item-8">
        <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-anchor-placement="center-bottom" data-aos-duration="1200">
          <div class="card right story-8" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modal8">
            <div class="card-body">

              <h5 class="card-subtitle ">Team Personnel Get Ready For The Bench Press</h5>
              <p class="card-time">10:00 AM</p>
            </div>
            <p class="card-more">Read More <i class="bi bi-arrow-right-circle"></i></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="item-9">
        <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-anchor-placement="center-bottom" data-aos-duration="1200">
          <div class="card left story-9" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modal9">
            <div class="card-body">

              <h5 class="card-subtitle ">"I wake up early and like to get a workout in"</h5>
              <p class="card-time">11:02 AM</p>
            </div>
            <p class="card-more">Read More <i class="bi bi-arrow-right-circle"></i></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="item-10">
        <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-anchor-placement="center-bottom" data-aos-duration="1200">
          <div class="card right story-10" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modal10">
            <div class="card-body">

              <h5 class="card-subtitle ">Team Personnel Get Ready For The Bench Press</h5>
              <p class="card-time">11:45 AM</p>
            </div>
            <p class="card-more">Read More <i class="bi bi-arrow-right-circle"></i></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="item-11">
        <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-anchor-placement="center-bottom" data-aos-duration="1200">
          <div class="card left story-11" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modal11">
            <div class="card-body">

              <h5 class="card-subtitle ">"I wake up early and like to get a workout in"</h5>
              <p class="card-time">12:15 PM</p>
            </div>
            <p class="card-more">Read More <i class="bi bi-arrow-right-circle"></i></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="item-12">
        <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-anchor-placement="center-bottom" data-aos-duration="1200">
          <div class="card right story-12" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modal12">
            <div class="card-body">

              <h5 class="card-subtitle ">Team Personnel Get Ready For The Bench Press</h5>
              <p class="card-time">2:15 PM</p>
            </div>
            <p class="card-more">Read More <i class="bi bi-arrow-right-circle"></i></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="item-13">
        <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-anchor-placement="center-bottom" data-aos-duration="1200">
          <div class="card left story-13" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modal13">
            <div class="card-body">

              <h5 class="card-subtitle ">"I wake up early and like to get a workout in"</h5>
              <p class="card-time">3:45 PM</p>
            </div>
            <p class="card-more">Read More <i class="bi bi-arrow-right-circle"></i></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="item-14">
        <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-anchor-placement="center-bottom" data-aos-duration="1200">
          <div class="card right story-14" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modal14">
            <div class="card-body">

              <h5 class="card-subtitle ">Team Personnel Get Ready For The Bench Press</h5>
              <p class="card-time">4:03 PM</p>
            </div>
            <p class="card-more">Read More <i class="bi bi-arrow-right-circle"></i></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="item-15">
        <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-anchor-placement="center-bottom" data-aos-duration="1200">
          <div class="card left story-15" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modal15">
            <div class="card-body">

              <h5 class="card-subtitle ">"I wake up early and like to get a workout in"</h5>
              <p class="card-time">4:42 PM</p>
            </div>
            <p class="card-more">Read More <i class="bi bi-arrow-right-circle"></i></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="item-16">
        <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-anchor-placement="center-bottom" data-aos-duration="1200">
          <div class="card right story-16" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modal16">
            <div class="card-body">

              <h5 class="card-subtitle ">Team Personnel Get Ready For The Bench Press</h5>
              <p class="card-time">5:05 PM</p>
            </div>
            <p class="card-more">Read More <i class="bi bi-arrow-right-circle"></i></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="item-17">
        <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-anchor-placement="center-bottom" data-aos-duration="1200">
          <div class="card left story-17" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modal17">
            <div class="card-body">

              <h5 class="card-subtitle ">"I wake up early and like to get a workout in"</h5>
              <p class="card-time">5:13 PM</p>
            </div>
            <p class="card-more">Read More <i class="bi bi-arrow-right-circle"></i></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="item-18">
        <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-anchor-placement="center-bottom" data-aos-duration="1200">
          <div class="card right story-18" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modal18">
            <div class="card-body">

              <h5 class="card-subtitle ">Team Personnel Get Ready For The Bench Press</h5>
              <p class="card-time">8:07 PM</p>
            </div>
            <p class="card-more">Read More <i class="bi bi-arrow-right-circle"></i></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="item-19">
        <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-anchor-placement="center-bottom" data-aos-duration="1200">
          <div class="card left story-19" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modal19">
            <div class="card-body">

              <h5 class="card-subtitle ">"I wake up early and like to get a workout in"</h5>
              <p class="card-time">9:03 PM</p>
            </div>
            <p class="card-more">Read More <i class="bi bi-arrow-right-circle"></i></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="item-20">
        <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-anchor-placement="center-bottom" data-aos-duration="1200">
          <div class="card right story-20" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modal20">
            <div class="card-body">

              <h5 class="card-subtitle ">Team Personnel Get Ready For The Bench Press</h5>
              <p class="card-time">10:30 PM</p>
            </div>
            <p class="card-more">Read More <i class="bi bi-arrow-right-circle"></i></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="item-21">
        <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-anchor-placement="center-bottom" data-aos-duration="1200">
          <div class="card left story-21" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modal21">
            <div class="card-body">

              <h5 class="card-subtitle ">"I wake up early and like to get a workout in"</h5>
              <p class="card-time">2:30 AM</p>
            </div>
            <p class="card-more">Read More <i class="bi bi-arrow-right-circle"></i></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- Scrollspy -->
  <script>
    var scrollSpy = new bootstrap.ScrollSpy(document.body, {
      target: '#navbar-example'
    })
  </script>
</body>
```